# Awk to Add [ ] in special characters

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to add [] if the column contains special characters or number except for a comma `,` at the end. The first line needs to be as it is in the file.

Current:

```
CREATE TEST 
a,
b,
23_test,
```

Expectation:

```
CREATE TEST 
a,
b,
[23_test],
```

Comment: What's a special character?  In the Unix world, underscore is a very ordinary and unspecial character.  It's a normal part of identifiers on Unix.

Comment: if it contains number in the column then I need to add [ ] before comma

Comment: Suppose a line contained "`13, dancing-elephants,`" — what's the required output?  Suppose a line contained "`13 dancing elephants`" — what's the required output?  What are the possible inputs?  What should be done if/when the input is impossible?   We don't know the context you're working in; we need to know enough to provide a sensible answer.

Comment: Then the output should be [13],[dancing-elephants], Need to add [ ] for special character column.

Comment: So, digits, punctuation other than comma, and spaces are all 'special characters'?  Are there any limits on the tools that can be used?  Is Perl OK?  Awk?  Python?  Sed?  Just Bash?  —— Please add your clarifications to the question, where you can format the information better.  Is the leading blank before the 'dancing' in "`13, dancing-elephants,`" significant or not?  Should it be omitted, or retained outside the square brackets, or retained inside the square brackets?  What about if there were three blanks instead of one?

Comment: I removed all the trailing space.I am writing shell script so, awk works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the *special characters* are digits, whitespaces, minus signs, plus signs, dots, and underscores (please modify the patten according to your definition), how about:

```
awk 'NR>1 && /[-0-9_+. ]/ {$0 = "[" gensub(",$", "", 1) "],"} {print}' input.txt
```

If you can be specific that the *special characters* are any characters other than alphabets and commas, try instead:

```
awk 'NR>1 && /[^a-zA-Z,]/ {$0 = "[" gensub(",$", "", 1) "],"} {print}' input.txt
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @tshiono I am getting below result. I need to remove comma before ]  a,
b,
[23_test, ],

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR>1 && /[-0-9_+. ]/ {$0 = "[" gensub(",$", "", 1) "],"} {print}' <filename.out> | sed 's/, ]/]/'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/23_test/,"[23_test]")}1' file

CREATE TEST 
a,
b,
[23_test],
```